# Correct way of using grunt's "bower_concat" and "angular-i18n"

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, group-concat

If one is not using grunt's "concat" and "bower_concat", angular-i18n is used this way:

```
 <html ng-app>
    <head>
        ...
       <script src="angular.js"></script>
       <script src="i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>
        ...
    </head>
 </html>
```

(According to here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n)

But... of course: I'm using `concat` and `bower_concat`.

I'm using them this way:

1. First I use bower_concat and create `build/bower-concat.js`
     **Note:** bower_concat reads every bower.json of every subdirectory living in `bower_components` and it concatenates all the main files.
     **Note 2:** the bower.json of "angular-18n" has `"ignore": ["**/.*", ...`
2. Then I concat all my js's (my controllers, etc), into `build/inouse-concat.js`
3. Finally I concat `bower-concat.js` with `inhouse-concat.js` into `all-concat.js`
4. `<script src="build/all-concat.js"></script>`

So I though that I could include the corresponding locale, "`angular-i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js`", in the third step, like this:

```
  // inhouse js with bower's js with angular's i18n into one file
  allJsConcat: {
    src: ['build/bower-concat.js', 'bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js', 'build/inhouse-concat.js',],
    dest: 'build/all-concat.js',
  }
```

But this is not working. I'm getting: 
 `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

**Question:** how would you recommend using grunt, concat, and bower_concat with angular's locale js? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Damn, I hate to answer my own questions because of rushing in asking...

Anyway, this worked:

Gruntfile.js

```
    bower_concat: {
        all: {
            dest: 'build/bower-concat.js',
            cssDest: 'build/bower-concat.css',
            exclude: [
                'angular-i18n'
            ],
            bowerOptions: {
                relative: false
            }
        }
    },

    concat: {
        ...

        allJsConcat: {
            src: ['build/bower-concat.js', 'bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js', 'build/inhouse-concat.js',],
            dest: 'build/all-concat.js',
        }
    }
```

The trick was using the `exclude` parameter of `grunt-bower-concat`.

There is also a `mainFiles` parameter that I think would do the trick too:

> mainFiles
>
> Some Bower components don’t list their main files or (more likely)
>   don’t have bower.json file at all. In this case bower-concat will try
>   to guess main file but sometimes it can’t or choose wrong one. You
>   could explicitly define main files for that components.

So I think that using this would work too:

```
 mainFiles: {
     'angular-i18n': 'angular-locale_de-de.js',
 }
```

Without doing the "three file concat" (so its more elegant)